# Expectation of the inverse of an almost surely convergent sequence

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence

Let $A_t$ be a bounded positive-semidefinite random matrix sequence, which converges a.s. to a positive definite matrix $A$.

Let $B > 0$ be a fixed positive definite matrix.

Consider the random matrix sequence: $C_t := \frac{B}{t} + A_t$

$C_t$ is positive-definite at any $t$ because $\frac{B}{t}$ is and thus is invertible.

Is the limit of the expectation of the inverse of $C_t$ bounded, i.e. $\lim_{t\to\infty} \mathbb{E} \|C_t^{-1}\| < \infty$?

Comment: $(A_t)_t$ is bounded in which sense?

Comment: $\|A_t\| \leq q < \infty$ for all t